# PHP Calling a method in instantiated class from parent class

Tags: php, inheritance

I have a parent class with below code:

```php
class ParentClass {
   public function parentMethod()
   {
      if (childMethodExist()) {
         $this->childMethod();
      }
   }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
   public function childMethod()
      // statement 1
      // statement 2
   }
}
```

Now I want to call `parentMethod()` which will intern call `childMethod()`. My problem is am I doing this correct (I already get eslint errors for `$this->childMethod();` in VSCode). But the code works as I expect.

Comment: _"I already get eslint errors"_ - I can understand that ESLint would throw errors if you ran that for this code, considering that it's for lining JavaScript, not PHP.

Comment: @M.Eriksson Thanks for pointing it out. I work on JS project at the same time. :) Anyway, Greg Schmidt knows what I was trying to tell and what my problem is, and also he knows that I am talking about intelephense. :D Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

What is `childMethodExist`? That should be `method_exists($this, 'childMethod')`, I'd say?

But a better way in general would be to overload the `parentMethod` in the child, something like:

```
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
    public function parentMethod() {
        // some child specific code might go here
 
       parent::parentMethod();

        // and some child specific code might go here
    }
}
```

Then, you just always call `$object->parentMethod()` from wherever you have something that's either a parent or a child, and it'll work. This way, your parent object doesn't know anything at all about the child object (which it shouldn't!), but its implementation is still used, so you prevent code duplication.